# POST API call having trouble with JSON body

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, rest, post

I'm trying to connect to an API and I keep getting an error saying that I'm not including the client_id in the call. Here's the code:

```
+ (void)connectWithUsername:(NSString *)username Password:(NSString *)password Type:(NSString *)type Email:(NSString *)email
{
    NSString *urlString = [kTestAPI stringByAppendingString:@"connect"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"client_id":client,
                         @"secret":secret,
                         @"credentials":@{@"username":username,@"password":password},
                         @"type":type,
                         @"email":email};
    NSLog(@"PARAMS: %@", params);
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:nil];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    request.HTTPBody = jsonData;

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSDictionary *output = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
         NSLog(@"SUCCESS: %@", output);
     }];
}
```

Here's the output:

```
2014-08-23 11:52:53.131 Balance[11538:60b] PARAMS: {
    "client_id" = "test_id";
    credentials =     {
        password = "plaid_good";
        username = "plaid_test";
    };
    email = "test@plaid.com";
    secret = "test_secret";
    type = wells;
}

2014-08-23 11:52:53.554 Balance[11538:60b] SUCCESS: {
    code = 1100;
    message = "client_id missing";
    resolve = "Include your Client ID so we know who you are.";
}
```

Initially, I thought it might be because the client_id is showing up in quotes when I NSLog it, but after doing some searching I found that apparently that is just a function of the description method that is called from NSLog since client_id has an underscore so it's not considered alphanumeric thus quotes are added, thus should not affect the JSON, I think. So, yeah I'm stumped, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: is it your api, maybe the issue is there?

Comment: have you tried testing the API via POSTMAN to ensure that API is working correctly?

Comment: Do you really want to POST JSON? Best read the API carefully.

Comment: Just spitballing here, but your API might require you to send a `content-type` header set to something like `application/json`.

Comment: Hey guys, @meda I used POSTMAN and the API is definitely working

Comment: @Zaph the type is POST. Here's the specs:

curl -X POST https://tartan.plaid.com/connect \
  -d client_id=test_id \
  -d secret=test_secret \
  -d credentials='{
      "username":"plaid_test",
      "password":"plaid_good"}' \
  -d type=wells \
  -d email=test@plaid.com

Comment: then maybe the webservice is expecting post variables, and not json as a post variable

Comment: Hey guys, I was able to get it to work using the stringified JSON method:

        NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"client_id=%@&secret=%@&credentials={\"username\":\"%@\",\"password\":\"%@\"}&type=%@&email=%@",client,secret,username,password,type,email];
        request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
        request.HTTPBody = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 But the specs say both methods (JSON and stringified JSON) should work, so would still like to solve this question if possible. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working: `curl -X POST tartan.plaid.com/connect \ -d client_id=test_id \ -d secret=test_secret \ -d credentials='{ "username":"plaid_test", "password":"plaid_good"}' \ -d type=wells \ -d email=test@plaid.com`

Notice that in the working curl `client_id`, `secret`, `type` and `email` are **not** part of the json but separate POST items. The JSOM item `credentials` has two items: `username` and `password` only.

You need to do the same in your code.
`client_id`, `secret`, `type`, `email` and `credentials` are POST variables. 'credentials' has a JSON string as it's value.

Comment: I see, thank you :) Would you mind explaining how one creates POST variables in the request?

Comment: One way is exactly what you did. A POST string which is essentially the same as a query string. Some 3rd party networking libraries have methods to make this easier such as accepting a NSDictionary and putting it together for you. Suggestion: Get Charles Proxy (free trial) and look at what is actually sent over the net, it can be instructive. I find Charles essential for solving network issues and figuring out what is really happening. It does HTTPS as well.